# Plotting maps using 'filled.contour'

Tags: r, plot, maps

I am plotting a map in R using 'filled.contour()' and I do not understand why this function switches the x,y axis. I have:

```
x=1:20
y=1:10
z=array(seq(1,2000,1),dim=c(length(y),length(x)) )
filled.contour(x,y,z,plot.title=title(main="Test",xlab="X",ylab="Y")  )
```

> Error in .filled.contour(x, y, z, levels, col) : dimension mismatch

but if I enter:

```
z=array(seq(1,2000,1),dim=c(length(x),length(y)) )
```

it plots the map correctly.
All documentation about arrays shows that 'dim' is defined as dim(y,x)
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what you are passing through the contour function. You have to pass x and y in the order that you set z as the dimensions of. So the reason that `z=array(seq(1,2000,1),dim=c(length(x),length(y)))` worked is because you called for

```
filled.contour(**x**,**y**,z,plot.title=title(main="Test",xlab="X",ylab="Y"))
```

The code below runs as you would hope.

```
x=1:20
y=1:10
z=array(seq(1,2000,1),dim=c(length(y),length(x)))
filled.contour(y,x,z,plot.title=title(main="Test",xlab="X",ylab="Y")  )
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. The point I am trying to make is that the codex=1:20
y=1:10
z=array(seq(1,2000,1),dim=c(length(y),length(x)) )

Comment: @Augusto did you run my code? It uses that exactly line, you have to just swap places of y and x when you call the plot as I show above in the code.

Comment: Thank you Adam, now I understand the behaviour of this function. I appreciate your help. Rgs,  Augusto

Comment: @Augusto please accept my answer by clicking the check mark if you found my solution helpful.